# Windows Defender update error

Tags: windows-8.1

Defender is disabled yet I keep getting bugged for and update that will not install (KB2267602) I have tried to hide it, install it manualy but the service is not running so it will not install. It just bugs me because it keeps trying to install with error..

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, i feel your pain. what you will have to do is re-enable the service (this is easy, as you are on windows 8.1. what you need to do is just open task managerm go to the services tab, and find the windows defender service, right click and enable ) and install the update. once the update is installed, just disable the service again.

Hope this helps